# Rewrite Rule with wildcard subdomain and optional extra parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am trying to write rewrite rules to accept a subdomain as well as an optional page on the end of the domain, example:

> a.domain.com
>   a.domain.com/1

Where "a" can be anything and the 1 is a numeric input.

I currently have the following conditions and rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.domain\.xyz
RewriteRule .* view.php?username=%1 [L]
```

which works with the subdomain, but cannot find a way to allow the second parameter on the end to work as well.

What rules can I add to make this work?

Comment: What do you expect to do with the second parameter?

Comment: It's just a numeric id to fetch something relating to the subdomain parameter

Comment: But where does it go? in the URL? in the query string? in a session cookie?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean... By URL do you mean as if you were loading it as a page? If so, then that.